# Entity Framework map between two tables with no keys using fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship, ef-fluent-api

Suppose I have two classes that represent two tables in my database:

```
class ThingA
{
    public int ThingAId { get; set; } // PK
    public string ThingAName { get; set; }
    public string ThingBName { get; set; }
    public ThingB ChildThing { get; set; }
}

class ThingB
{
    public int ThingBId { get; set; } // PK
    public string ThingBName { get; set; }
}
```

Most things in the database relate to these two entities using the primary key as you'd expect, however, for reasons I won't go into `ThingA` has an instance of `ThingB` inside it but these two records are related by the `ThingBName` column present in both tables. `ThingBName` is neither a foreign key or primary key on either table (I know).

Is there a way to map this using Fluent API so that when I retrieve a `ThingA` record `ThingB` will be loaded into the `ChildThing` property according to the relationship using `ThingBName`?

I hope I've explained this well enough. Thanks in advance.

Note that `ThingB` is related to in lots of places in the database so I don't really want a reference to `ThingA` inside `ThingB`.

Comment: It appears you could do this in EF Core: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#no-foreign-key-property

Comment: Thanks I thought it might not be possible in EF6

Comment: @Eris That refers to having a primitive foreign key property or not. But in EF, entities have one primary key and *all* associations must refer to that key.